# Spring Boot / JPA / Hibernate, How to switch database vendor according to Spring profile?

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot, profile

I'm using Spring Boot / JPA / Hibernate. I would like to use HSQLDB when testing on localhost and MySQL when deploying on server.

In pom.xml, I have this dependency for MySQL :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and this dependency for HSQLDB :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I probably can't put both dependencies in pom.xml due to Spring Boot autoconfiguration. But I would like to use HSQLDB when the `local` Spring profile is active and use MySQL when the `server` Spring profile is active. Ideally, I would like to generate only one war file and running the local version with `mvn spring-boot:run` and deploy the server version from the war file.

Any idea?

P.S.: I'm using maven

Comment: Which issue do you have if both dependencies are set? Is the application not starting correctly? Or something else

Comment: Maybe you can implement two different datasources in your application and let the profile value deceide which datasource is used.

Comment: @Patrick After some more investigations, I found that, the issue is coming from sql dialect incompatibility between MySQL and HSQLDB, but Stephane Nicoll is right there is no problem having both dependencies in pom.xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I probably can't put both dependencies in pom.xml due to Spring Boot autoconfiguration.

Sure you can have both of them. There are several solutions.

The most basic one is to have both dependencies and create an `application-server.properties` in your project with the settings of your mysql database. When you run the app with no particular profile, Spring Boot won't find any information to connect to MySQL so it'll fallback to HSQL. When you deploy your app on the server, make sure to enable the `server` profile. The same artifact can be used for both use cases.

You could improve that solution a bit by excluding the hsql dependency when you generate the fat jar. This has the advantage that if you forget to enable the profile you'll get an exception on startup rather than silently use an in-memory databae. To exclude hsql, simply [configure the maven plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html). You'll be able tot run the app locally (`mvn spring-boot:run`) or in your IDE and the fat jar will only contain the mysql dependency. You'll still have to enable the `server` profile though.

If you're using a war, you can't use that last solution: one more reason to switch to jar ;-)

Comment: Why is it not possible to exclude hsql from war file?

Comment: You can. But if you need to run the war file and you exclude it, you won't be able to run your app with an in-memory database. When you have a jar, you can run your app directly from the IDE

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a **Maven Profile** not a spring profile and add the dependency accordily. Create a *local* profile with hsqldb dependency and activate it while in dev mode. Then create a *server* profile with the mysql dependency and activate it while packaging for deploy on server. I personally prefer *dev* and *release* as a naming convention ( but it is my humble opinion). Then you have to shortcut the **maven profile** with the **spring profile**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>xyz</version>
    <configuration>
      <profiles>
        <profile>local</profile>....
```

In local profile and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
      <profiles>
        <profile>server</profile>...
```

in server profile and the run the desired configuration with this switch

```
mvn spring-boot:run -P[local or server]
```

[Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: This is a good solution but he has to create two war files for test and prod, right?

Comment: @Patrick It's the solution used in our company project. The production profile minifies JS and CSS sources to improve our page load times. We use `mvn clean package -Prelease` to create the prod war file. Not minifying on every build also saves us annoying waiting time during development.

Comment: @patrick it depends : for test and prod is advisable to use the same db ( so mysql) . he has to create two war: one for development and one for release ( for test and production). this is why I suggest to change naming convention

Comment: @Sammyrulez In fact, I've three Spring profile combinations : `local` for testing on my local machine (HSQLDB), `server,dev` for testing on the production environment (MySQL) and `server` for deploying on the production environment (MySQL).

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni spring profile or maven profile? sorry but it's not clear

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I edited the answer and prepared this gist with a complete example https://gist.github.com/sammyrulez/53286a1162414e5f7a5871c7f3df3ca3